# How to use a nested loop to count up then down?

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I cannot figure out how to count up and then down using a nested loop. Currently, my output is:

```
2
33
444
5555
66666
```

When I wanted it to output like this:

```
2
33
444
33
2
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. I've been working on this forever, and cannot seem how to switch things around to make it work.

Here is my current code that produces the first output:

Answer (score 3):

This output has two interesting properties. For each row `i` we can say that:

1. The number of characters in each row is the minimum between `i` and `times - i`.
2. The character to print is the number of characters in that row + 1.

If you put that all together:

```
int lines = 3;
int times = lines * 2;
String output = "";
for(int i = 1; i < times; i++)
{
    int numChar = Math.min(i, times - i);
    int toPrint = numChar + 1;
    for(int k = 1; k < toPrint; k++) {
        output += toPrint;
    }

    output += "\n";
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: So I understand this. But for another output like if I had lines = 5, and I wanted it to start from 8 and count down then up, meaning like this: (check edit above)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the second of your inner loops does nothing, it never starts, only the first one produces output. I think your idea was close to having four loops, nested two by two. That would work, but you only need two nested loops, used cleverly.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int lines = 3;
    int times = lines * 2;
    int x = 2;
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < times; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k <= Math.min(times-i, i); k++) {
            output = output + x;
        }

        //Update the index
        if (i < times/2) {
            x++;
        } else  {
            x--;
        }

        output += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The trick is in how you use the index of the second loop: `Math.min(times-i, i)`.

EDIT:
After your Edit, it looks like you want the numbers to "spin around" (i.e. ...8,9,0,1...). In order to achieve that, you can do in the inner loop:

```
            String xS = String.valueOf(x);
            output += xS.charAt(xS.length()-1);
```

Another option (outside the inner loop):

```
        //Update the index
        if (i <= (times/2) - 1) {
            x++;
        } else  {
            x--;
        }
        x = x%10; //the rest of dividing x by 10
        output += "\n";
    }
```

Comment: I see this. That works also, but how can I make it reset to 0 and count up to 2 then back down because currently when x starts at 8 and counts up it goes to 10 12 etc.

Comment: I see. that works, but once it gets to "22222" it continues back to 3333, 444, etc when I needed it to once it gets to the middle value to count back down. (check output code above in original post)

Comment: @JohnathanMinucco Updated the answer to match the requirements